# How to toggle RPi GPIO without system call

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I want to toggle GPIO from within my C application, and be sure that it won't call kernel functions. Is wiringPi a good solution to do that, or should I do it another way?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to call kernel functions?  Which ones don't you want called?  This seems to be an odd request.

Comment: I am developing a priority inversion demo application using pthreads for my master thesis purpose. To prove that priority inversion actually occured, in each thread I want to keep toggling gpio pin so that it would be visible which thread is executing on kind of execution chart. If i use any system call then it might cause some mismatches in execution chart due to system call's highest priority.

Comment: I'm aware that it may be an odd approach, but I am struggling to get any kind of applications "thread execution in time" output and this is just another idea of how to achieve it

Comment: I need to get something like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Priority-inversion-example-all-scheduling-latencies-are-assumed-null_fig3_331290349) out of my application

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do (which is far from clear) wiringpi (which has been deprecated) is not the answer. There are many libraries which access GPIO via /dev/gpiomem

Comment: You should edit some of the information from comments into your question. As far as I'm aware, those libraries use `mmap()` in initialization, but thereafter access to that memory does not require a system call.  **You could always just run a simple demo w/ `strace` to determine this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiringPi, pigpio, and bcm2835 libraries can each toggle the GPIO without involving the Linux kernel.

For links to the libraries see https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples

In practice you will need to be doing busy spins (i.e. no delays or sleeps) as any delays or sleeps you use will likely use kernel calls to implement.